# Does Pantheon work without 3d acceleration?

Tags: 12.04, 3d, pantheon

I installed **Pantheon DE** on my **12.04** laptop, which doesn't support 3d acceleration but Pantheon seems to don't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: I forgot to say that I've already installed LLVMpipe, infact gnome 3 runs...

Comment: It would be better to add information by editing the question rather than by adding comments. You can do so at any time you like. Then, you can delete your comment since it will no longer serve any purpose. And when you mention "gnome 3", give the full version like GNOME 3.2 or 3.4 or 3,6.

Answer (score 1):

Pantheon *can* run without 3D acceleration, but only if you use a different Window manager. This is because Pantheon's default window manager (Gala) requires it. You could use Metacity instead.

You need to edit `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon.session` and change the Window Manager to Metacity. By the way, you need to have Metacity installed for this to work. You can also use other Window managers such as Xfwm and Openbox.